# Prevent Tkinter button presses from queuing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a small project with a raspberry pi and a 2.8" capacitive touchscreen. I am new to python and I need to prevent multiple button presses from queuing.  The desired behavior is for the UI to ignore any button presses while the previous buttonpress is being executed.  Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#pin assignments
A=11
B=13
C=15
D=12
E=16
FAN=8

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(A, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(B, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(C, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(D, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(E, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(FAN, GPIO.OUT)

class App:
  def fanOn(self):
    GPIO.output(FAN,True)
  def fanOff(self):
    GPIO.output(FAN,False)
  def btnClicked(self,atty):
    GPIO.output(atty,True)
    self.fanOn()
    time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(atty,False)
    self.fanOff()
  def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.buttonA = Button(frame, text="Fire A", fg="red", command=lambda: self.btnClicked(A))
    self.buttonA.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.buttonB = Button(frame, text="Fire B", fg="red", command=lambda: self.btnClicked(B))
    self.buttonB.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.buttonC = Button(frame, text="Fire C", fg="red", command=lambda: self.btnClicked(C))
    self.buttonC.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.buttonD = Button(frame, text="Fire D", fg="red", command=lambda: self.btnClicked(D))
    self.buttonD.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.buttonE = Button(frame, text="Fire E", fg="red", command=lambda: self.btnClicked(E))
    self.buttonE.pack(side=LEFT)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your application _really_ calling `time.sleep(5)`? If not, tell us what it's really doing. if it _is_, there's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do. As a general rule, the main thread of a GUI program should never call `time.sleep`.

Comment: Like i said, very new to python and this type of programming in general.  I am indeed really calling time.sleep(). I am trying to use tkinter buttons to trigger a control signal that opens a mosfet, and i need it to stay open for 5 seconds.  What would the better way be?

Comment: You can disable the buttons and enable them when done, or pack_forget() and then pack them when done.  See the "state=" parameter at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm  If you want to disable for a certain amount of time, then the current time, as the first line in the function, must be x greater than the previous time of execution, otherwise a simple return will exit the function with no action taken.